# How to print from aspx page without opening print dialog box

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing

I want to print from aspx page (body part {}). But I don't want to open print dialog box. i have already installed more then one printer are in my computer. But when i click on print button its directly print in my default printer. How can i do it or is it possible to do it in web application?

Comment: Where from it is printing right now?Not from your .aspx page?

Comment: ya now i do it from aspx page.... but when i click on print button show the dialog box. i do not want it.....

Answer (score 1):

Print is handled by the browser, not your ASPX page. So you can't do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that for all browsers. Printing is client side, and you can't pass the print dialog.

There is a [old script](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=85301), but it doesn't work anythere exept IE and Netscape. And it is very old:

```
function printit() {
  if ((navigator.appName == "Netscape")) { 
    window.print() ; 
  } else { 
    var WebBrowser = '<OBJECT ID="WebBrowser1" WIDTH=0 HEIGHT=0 CLASSID="CLSID:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2"></OBJECT>';
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', WebBrowser); 
    WebBrowser1.ExecWB(6, -1); WebBrowser1.outerHTML = ""; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can, but you'll need to use a third party class\assembly that does it like

pdf.sharp

or just write one yourself...

Comment: thnks a lot..... do you have any link or sample code that help me for doing this....

Comment: can u share any links for details...?

Answer (score 0):

add iframe

```
 <iframe id="ifmcontentstoprint" style="height: 0px; width: 0px; position: absolute"></iframe>
```

and use follwing javascript function

```
 function printform() {
        var content = document.getElementById('<%= PrintDivID.ClientID %>').innerHTML;

        var pri = document.getElementById("ifmcontentstoprint").contentWindow;
        pri.document.open();
        pri.document.write(content);
        pri.document.close();
        pri.focus();
        pri.print();
    }
```